# Django auto select empty value in multiplechoiecfield

Tags: python, django

I have a MultipleChoiceField in Django 1.11 and it auto selects the empty value in the rendered output what is not desired.
`(u'', '(no extra)')` should be not auto selected on load.

```
choices = [(u'', '(no extra)'), (u'cheese', u'Cheese'), (u'Pepper', u'Pepper')]
extra_topics = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, choices=choices)
```

Is there any flag that I can prevent this?

Comment: I think you have to change the the empty string from `(u'', '(no extra)')` in order to prevent the auto-selection. Maybe use `(u'no-extra', '(no extra)')` or don't use it at all?

Comment: Yep, this would be a different way to handle it.

Comment: looking at the [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.3/django/forms/widgets.py#L601) I don't see other way around.

Comment: hmm I see. Maybe it would be good to check there beforehand if a `value` already was returned before doing the check with `subvalue` selected check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an Django bug and is fixed in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.11.12/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0.4/

Answer (score 1):

You can set the initial value as whatever you want I.E.

```
extra_topics = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, 
      choices=choices, 
      initial={'not empty': 'not empty'})
```

Hope I'm not misunderstanding your question and good luck.

Comment: there should be no initial. I try that (no extra) is not auto selected on load.

Comment: What is displayed initially in that field?

Comment: all three values and no-extra is selected. https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.3/django/forms/widgets.py#L601 There is the reason